# PyArrow dataset to_table().to_pandas() empty due to bug or timeout?

Tags: python, pandas, pyarrow

I have a PyArrow [`dataset`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.dataset.dataset.html#pyarrow.dataset.dataset) pointed to a folder directory with a lot of subfolders containing `.parquet` files. I am using the dataset to filter-while-reading the `.parquet` files to a [`Table`](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.Table.html#pyarrow.Table), then to convert it to a [`pandas DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).

The `.parquet` files all have a [`DatetimeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) with 1 minute frequency and when I read them, I just need the last 20 minutes (rows) of data.

The `.parquet` files I am reading are constantly updated every 5 seconds by another process. I can guarantee that there are not race conditions or conflict between the processes writing and reading same files, I have already carefully managed all those problems.

What I noticed is that when I read the last 20 minutes of data, for exactly 20 minutes there are no problems, but after approximately 20 minutes when I try to read again the same files with the same conditions, the returning pandas `DataFrame` becomes empty.

Weird.

I tried changing the window to 40 minutes, and for approximately 40 minutes everything is fine, but then on the n-th read the returned pandas `DataFrame` is empty.

Weirder.

So I quickly defined an identical dataset on a Python interactive shell and tried to read the exact same files with the exact same condition and function too, and guess what? The returned DataFrame **is not** empty.

What the duck?

So I tried to read a 60 minutes window guessing that after approximately 60 minutes the DataFrame will magically become empty...and I was right.

So there is a correletation between the length of data that I am actually reading and for how much time I am able to read it correctly.

<del>I am running this code on Fedora 37 64bit with Btrfs as filesystem on a Ryzen 9 5950X. I am giving you this information because the idea I came up with is that it may be a problem related to the filesytem or related to PyArrow + Btrfs.</del>

Another idea, but here I admit that I am just wondering maybe too much, is that when you define a `dataset(...)`, on creation it probably creates a pool of threads (to read the data faster) and this pool has some sort of timeout that could be determined by the first "query" that you pass to it and so, after that time the pool is closed for some reason and since there are no threads reading the files (and maybe some exception is passing silently), the returned `DataFrame` is empty?

I repeat, I am just guessing here, but it's driving me crazy since yersterday.

I tried with PyArrow 9.0.0 and PyArrow 10.0.0, with no differences. Can someone illuminate me on what it's going on? Thank you.

Comment: I forgot: I define the `dataset` **after** I am certain that the files I need to read already exist, so their path can be scanned and listed on the dataset.files.

Comment: Update: I got the same problem with XFS filesystem, so it's something else.